# Calculate the leading-order asymptotic behaviour (Laplace's Method)

Tags: asymptotics

thanks in advance!

Calculate the leading-order asymptotic behaviour of the integral
$$I(x) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} (1+t^2) e^{x \cos t} dt \mbox{ as } x \mbox { tends to infinity}$$

So far I know there are two maximas at $0 \mbox{ and }2\pi$ so it can be assumed to be the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon} (1+t^2) e^{x \cos t} dt + \int_{2\pi-\epsilon}^{2\pi} (1+t^2) e^{x \cos t} dt$$
then using taylor expansions this can be transformed to:
$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon} (1+t^2) e^{x (1-\frac{t^2}{2})} dt + \int_{2\pi-\epsilon}^{2\pi} (1+t^2) e^{x (1-\frac{1}{2}(t-2\pi)^2)} dt$$
but where do I go from here? How do I find the leading order term?